# Stripe embeddable buy button opens new browser tab

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying out Stripe payments for a website and to start with I would like use a simple payment link.
However, there is an option to use an embedded buy button (Card or Button) which looks nice but when I click on it, on my laptop,  the Stripe site is opened in a new tab/window.
I would like the Stripe payment details to open in the current browser window (similar to target="_self"). Is that possible to do?

Below is the code (as generated by Stripe)

```
<script async
  src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js">
</script>

<stripe-buy-button
  buy-button-id="buy_btn_1NiOHcFGHWXsQN6nUdABzTMU"
  publishable-key="pk_test_51Nfkm3FGHWXsQN6nbqGxs9gSMbhu6rKBzxhfE3EFhKIAzqOdb7KKYi3U3avrbTOOYTQwAm0pWu0yohm0cgcHQS8m00LPt0gLuo"
>
</stripe-buy-button>
```

I've looked through stripe documents and web but not found any info on this. When using simple  link without any stripe java-script code it is possible to open Stripe in current browser window.

Answer (score 1):

I think this behavior is intended.

Unlike Checkout Sessions, Payment Links don't have a `cancel_url`, meaning you can't have a 'back'  arrow that redirects you to the previous page on a Payment Link. This would explain why buy-buttons open a new tab rather than assign/replace the window location.

I you want to produce a different behavior, then I'd suggest using HTML / JS to redirect to the Payment Link url yourself.

--EDIT
Since you like the visuals of the Payment Link buy-button, you might like Pricing Tables:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table

They look very similar, and redirect on the same page (they don't have a `cancel_url` either but they do have a 'back' button, so maybe my hunch from earlier is still valid).

Comment: Pricing table is for Subscription and can't be used for one-time payment, so pricing table might not be helpful if the asker is looking for one-time payment solution.

Comment: Nice comment... Have you tried creating a Pricing Table for a one-time Price ? I think you might get a surprise ;) ;) ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I see your point with no cancel_url. 
However when using the 'Redirect customers to your website' functionality (as I'm doing with this link in this test) it seems strange to me that the user end up with two tabs/windows to my site after the payment has been done.

Comment: This 'Redirect customers to your website' is an equivalent of the `success_url`, which isn't the same as the `cancel_url`. The `success_url` is the confirmation page after the session is completed. The `cancel_url` is the page you're redirected to if you press the 'back' arrow

Comment: I think this is kind of a design issue on Stripe - Payment Links were initially intended for messaging with your customers, hence why they wouldn't have a `cancel_url` or 'back' arrow that leads you to the previous page. Pricing Tables were always intended to be embedded on your website, so there is this 'back' arrow. It kinda feels like Payment Links buy-buttons were an afterthought, and this whole lack of 'back'  arrow is the reason why you're seeing this different behavior

Answer (score 0):

Pay Button doesn't support changing how the Payment link is open. If you wish to have the Payment Link in the same tab/window, it's possible to use [`window.location.href`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp) to redirect to the Payment Link URL directly without having any Stripe related JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create your own HTML button with a stripe Payment Link URL

for example

```
<a href="<Your Payment Link URL>" class="button">Buy</a>
```